# MySql Join 3 Tables where two tables are joined and then a third after

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables I would like to join.
vm, ds and tp

vm joins with ds 
ds joins with tp

I only want to match with the original query below that returns 8703 and return a single row from the other tables so I end up with 8703 rows in the end.

```
`SELECT *
FROM vm 
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from vm)`
```

This returns 8703 results as expected.

I then want to use the above table and join it with another table to retrieve some more values.

## Second Query to join

```
`SELECT *
FROM ds 
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from ds)`
```

I want to join the above two on:

`INNER JOIN ds ON vm.datastore = ds.DatastoreName`

## Third Query to join

```
`SELECT *
FROM tp 
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) from tp)`
```

I want to join tables ds and tp on:

```
`INNER JOIN tp ON ds.uid = tp.uid`
```

I have tried the following but it returns 30,000 thousand rows and I only want the 8703 from above.

## Full Query:

```
`SELECT *
FROM vm 
INNER JOIN ds ON vm.datastore = ds.DatastoreName
INNER JOIN tp ON ds.uid = tp.uid
WHERE vm.date = (SELECT MAX(date) from vm)
AND ds.date = (SELECT MAX(date) from ds)
AND tp.date = (SELECT MAX(date) from tp)`
```

I have also tried many versions of the above over the last 8 hours.

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Comment: What should your required result look like?

Comment: Your INNER JOINs are expanding the result - from 8703 to 30,000 - because there are probably multiple `DatastoreName` in `ds` for each `datastore` in `vm`. Have you tried `GROUP BY ds.DatastoreName`?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Fredster Your idea worked for me, while it was not GROUP BY ds.DatastoreName it was group by on the vm.id column to get the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Your INNER JOINs are expanding the result - from 8703 to 30,000 - because there are probably multiple DatastoreName in ds for each datastore in vm.

Have you tried GROUP BY vm.id?